# how to make intellisense prefer local variables?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When typing, autocomplete gives me multiple options. In many cases, although there's a local variable/class in the list, vscode suggests it as 3/4th option, and pushes to the top classes that belong in modules/packages that have not even been imported yet. This often causes me to accidentally push tab and import them.

Is there a way to instruct vscode to "prefer" already existing/local names?

Comment: This might depend on the extension you use for autocomplete, and on the programming language.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: good point, however I noticed it in multiple languages, so I wonder if  there might be a central option